# Why are assets suddenly 'not found' in a Rails 4 production env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In a mature Rails 4 app, assets are suddenly not found - css, images, js, all.

Everything works fine in development, and did work in production until recently.

We have pushed some code updates, but nothing obvious that would cause this, and I'm struggling to know where to begin debugging.

Interestingly, if I examine the page source, it looks like the assets are not having a digest assigned. I did not think this was possible in Rails 4? Plus the config switch for asset digests is definitely true for production.

Where should I look to begin debugging this?

Comment: Have you looked at your logs on server startup? Perhaps something is failing there?

Comment: did you not forget to do rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=PRODUCTION ?

Answer (score 0):

About css not working, most probably because you forgot to do the

`rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

and about the images not showing, try to change your html code to

`<%= image_tag 'foldername/image.jpg' %>`

that if you have a folder under `/assets/images`

and don't forget to do the assets precompile every time.

Comment: Thanks Mac, I am deploying to heroku, and Assets:precompile is called automatically during deploy. At least, that is how it has worked up till now, has something changed?

Comment: @AndyHarvey by production, i haven't thought of heroku...anyway, how about your config.serve_static_assets... is it true?

Comment: Yes, it is set to true

Comment: read here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline
and it would be best if you can post some of your related codes in your question

Comment: Thanks Mac, I'm more than happy to provide code. The problem is, I don't know what code to provide. Assets were working perfectly until recently, and there are no obvious candidates as to which code is to blame. I will review recent commits more carefully later today, and will post anything that jumps out. Otherwise, I'm greatful for any advise as to how to systematically debug this. Thanks!

Comment: Try changing Rails.application.co fig.assets.version to 1.1 in assets.rb

Comment: gemfile, production.rb, html codes under /view and css

just those codes that involves images or whatever problem you are encountering.